# How to display two pieces of information in the same python `print`

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to display the size of the products on this page:

I can get the size of the products this way:

```
request = requests.get("https://www.nike.com.br/air-jordan-7-153-169-211-315592")
tamanho = re.findall(r'"Tamanho":"(.*?)"', request.text)                                        
joined = f'\n'.join([str(elem) for elem in tamanho])
print(joined)
```

And I can get information about the products that are in stock with this code:

```
request = requests.get("https://www.nike.com.br/air-jordan-7-153-169-211-315592")
estoque = re.findall(r'"TemEstoque":"(.*?)"', request.text)                                     
estoque_formated = '\n'.join([str(elem) for elem in estoque])
print(estoque_formated)
```

With the code above I can get the products that are in stock, but how can I display the product that is in stock along with the product size?  In the same `print` in the case, I want to display the product size and stock number together, how can I do this?

The script output I wanted looked like this:

```
Size: 20 In stock: 0
```

Comment: why not just simply `print(joined + " " + estoque_formated)`?

Comment: @Burnalc It displays all sizes and after that breaks the line and then displays all products in stock, so it doesn't work

Comment: Probably I do not understand your question. Do you want to print `tamanho[0] estoque[0]` then `tamanho[1] estoque[1]`,etc. ?

Comment: @VPfB Try running the code in my question, it displays all sizes without me needing to access the index, and also the second snippet of code displays the products in stock, I just want to display both in a `print` wish I could do this `print( f"Sizes: {joined} In stock: {estoque_formated}`) but if you try to do this you will get a clearer picture of the problem

Comment: @Gjsks Please show the data, not the source webpages.

Comment: Run the first snippet of code in my question, then run the second, I want to display the two data together, the size and the product in stock

Comment: I put the code in the question, but if they don't run, it's complicated to explain with texts sometimes

Comment: @VPfB Have you tried running the code on your terminal?

Comment: @Dakota No, I did not. There were several answers posted and the OP has not responded if they solved the problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

Python supports a couple of ways of doing this. So as not to overlap with the other answers, here are a few other ways to do it.

The simplest is to just pass multiple arguments into print, and it will automatically display them all.

```
print("Size:", 20, "In stock: ", 0)
```

for example. You could also use Python's formatting operator, which lets you use printf-style format strings,

```
print("Size: %d In Stock: %d" % (20, 0))
```

Note the extra set of parenthesis. This operator generally works like this,

```
<string> % <tuple>
```

So if you want to use it, you should list out a tuple containing the values you want to substitute in to the slots in your format string.

Assuming your two arrays are of equal length, you can chuck either of those options into a simple for-loop to get the job done,

```
for i in range(len(tamanho)):
    print("Size: %d In Stock: %d" % (tamanho[i], estoque[i]))
```

Comment: The sizes and products in stock are dynamic, so it won't always be the example I mentioned in the question

Comment: Right--just replace the number with a variable representing the desired quantity then. I just added a for-loop example at the end to cover your case with the arrays you have, if you wanted to print all of the data out line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

The're the same length, and product rows line up?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import re

request = requests.get("https://www.nike.com.br/air-jordan-7-153-169-211-315592")
tamanho = re.findall(r'"Tamanho":"(.*?)"', request.text)                                        

request = requests.get("https://www.nike.com.br/air-jordan-7-153-169-211-315592")
estoque = re.findall(r'"TemEstoque":"(.*?)"', request.text)                                     

for i in range( len( tamanho ) ):
    print( f'Size: { tamanho[i] },  In stock: { estoque[i] }' )
```

> Size: 20,  In stock: 0
> Size: 34,  In stock: 0
> Size: 34,5,  In stock: 0
> Size: 35,  In stock: 0
> ...

Answer (score 0):

In the lines where you create `joined` and `estoque_formatted` you are effectively 'trapping' the data by creating one long string that extends over many lines and is difficult to work with, and then you are trying to combine the two after the fact. Try this approach of grabbing the data for each row before converting that data to a string.

You essentially have two columns of data, and want to grab one piece of data from each to make a row. `zip` is a convenient function for doing this.

```py
for size,inventory in zip(tomanho, estoque):
  print(f'Size: {size} In stock: {inventory}')
```

Give it a try and see if it produces the output you want.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.